# Jupyter Notebook does not run in Pycharm Professional (but runs in browser)

Tags: browser, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, jupyter

after running a cell in a Jupyter Notebook (the following command runs automatically by PyCharm in the Jupyter Console):

```
"C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2020.2.3\\bin\\runnerw.exe" D:\\python_projects\\semantic_search\\venv_chroma_python311\\Scripts\\python.exe -m jupyter notebook --no-browser --notebook-dir=D:/python_projects/semantic_search
```

I get an option to open a notebook in the browser

```
To access the server, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/ilija/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-2584-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8890/tree?token=277d38f20f0ac539391abcd2480b543d81f4d7693582b0f6
        http://127.0.0.1:8890/tree?token=277d38f20f0ac539391abcd2480b543d81f4d7693582b0f6
```

But, the cell that I ran in Pycharm keeps on buffering, and I cannot execute it inside of Pycharm.

[Image from cell not running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v43S2.png)

What can I do to fix this?

I tried running the same command in terminal with "--no-browser", but does not work.